# Problems with basename in a loop

Tags: shell-script, filenames, wildcards, quoting, basename

I am new at shell script programming and I'm trying to execute a software that reads a text and perform it's POS tagging. It requires an input and an output, as can be seen in the execute example:

```
$ cat input.txt | /path/to/tagger/run-Tagger.sh > output.txt
```

What I'm trying to do is to execute this line not only for a text, but a set of texts in an specific folder, and return the output files with the same name as the input files. So, I tried to do this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/"
program="/home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/LX-Tagger/POSTagger/Tagger/run-Tagger.sh"

for arqin in '/home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/teste/*'
do
out=$(basename $arqin)
output=$path$out
cat $arqin | $program > $output
done
```

I tried it with only one file and it works, but when I try with more than one, I get this error:

```
basename: extra operand ‘/home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/teste/3’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.

./scriptLXTagger.sh: 12: ./scriptLXTagger.sh: cannot create /home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/: Is a directory
```

Any insights on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've put single quotes around `'/home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/teste/*'`. This means that it is looking for a single file called `*` inside `teste`. (I doubt you have such a file, or that that's what you intended!).

This means your `for` loop is running with a single entry, and passing that file `*` to basename.

Then, `out=$(basename $arqin)` is expanding to `out=$(basename file1 file2 file3 ... fileN)` which of course is too many arguments for basename.

Simple solution: take the quotes away from around `/home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/teste/*`.

Answer (score 1):

@BenXO already told you why that failed but you don't really need a script for something this simple anyway. You could just paste this directly into the command line:

```
for arqin in /home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/teste/*; do 
    cat "$arqin" | 
      /home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/LX-Tagger/POSTagger/Tagger/run-Tagger.sh > \
        /home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/$(basename "$arqin"); 
done
```

Or, since if `cat foo | program` works, `program foo` almost certainly also works and assuming that `/home/rafaeldaddio/` is your home directory, you can simplify to:

```
for arqin in ~/Documents/teste/*; do
 ~/Documents/LX-Tagger/POSTagger/Tagger/run-Tagger.sh "$arqin" > \
     ~/Documents/$(basename "$arqin");
done
```